# Windows server 2008 x86 install fails

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

A students install is failing after he enters the key with error
"Windows installation has encountered an error and needs to be restarted"

It seems a few people have run into this

http://thebackroomtech.com/2008/05/14/windows-server-2008-installation-error-windows-installation-has-encountered-an-error-and-needs-to-be-restarted/

Tonite we re-downloaded - re-burned and re-installed, yet get the same issue. This is a dreamspark download with a legal key. If there is a way to continue the install without entering a key we could not figure it out.

Does anyone know what the solution is?

Comment: Please ask this question on superuser.com .

Comment: ......or ServerFault

Comment: You can do better than accepting an answer for less than **half** of your questions asked! Please get in the habit of accepting the best answer provided, the one solving your problem - it's the nice and right thing to do for all those who take their time to read and answer your questions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Server 2008 can be installed without providing any key; it will work for 30 days without requiring activation.

After the installation is complete, you can enter a key and activate it anytime you want (before the 30-days trial period ends).

Comment: IM sorry, but we were not able to get the installer to go past requesting the key. Is there some trick to this or perhaps it triggers a flag if you try to enter a key?

Comment: It usually just gives you a warning and then goes on happily if you confirm.